# jQuery click event not firing on button element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple If statement that checks if a checkbox is check or not that is called on a click event, however the click event appears to not be working.

I've for two dummy alerts into the if just to see if it being hit or not but neither of them are.

HTML:

```
 <input id="cookie-checkbox" name="cookie-checkbox" class="cookie-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked><label for="cookie-checkbox">I give consent for the use of cookies on this website.</label><br /><br />
 <button id="cookiesbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
            $('#cookiesbutton').click(cookiesDismiss());            
});

function cookiesDismiss() {
    var cookieConsent = $('#cookie-checkbox');

    if (!cookieConsent.checked) {
        alert("Cookie removed");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Modal hidden");
    }
}
```

I have a fiddle set up with the code at: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WebDevelopWolf/zuz5qLnt/4/)

I'm almost sure that I'm missing something really, really small and simple, but I just can't seem to see it.

Comment: I'm sure you know what is the difference between function call and a reference. Just apply that knowlede here. Also, wrapping a function in parents alone doesn't make it IIFE, you've to use `()` operator as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give the click handler the *reference* to your `cookiesDismiss()` function, not the *result* of the function.

Also note that you need to precede the document ready handler with a `$`, and `checked` is not a property of a jQuery object; you need to use `prop('checked')` to get the state of the checkbox.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cookiesbutton').click(cookiesDismiss); // note the removal of ()
});

function cookiesDismiss() {
    var cookieConsent = $('#cookie-checkbox');

    if (!cookieConsent.prop('checked')) {
        alert("Cookie removed");
    } else {
        alert("Modal hidden");
    }
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/zuz5qLnt/8/)

Comment: Why don't you say what else was wrong here instead of fixing it in am offsite resource! Better yet use a snipplet.

Comment: @epascarello was in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add parentheses "**()**" to a function its get executed/evaluated at that time only and in your case it assigned the evaluated value of the function instead of actual function.

**Eample:**

Where "**target**" is the ID of the html control.

```
   $( "#target" ).click(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
```

**or**

```
 $( "#target" ).click(showAlert);

 function showAlert(){  
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." ); 
 }
```

> **In your case:**

As funation name is "**cookiesDismiss**" it should be as below mentioned code:

<s>$('#cookiesbutton').click(cookiesDismiss())</s>

```
(function () {
       $('#cookiesbutton').click(cookiesDismiss);            
});
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Your example is actually lacking those parentheses needed to execute a function ; ).

Answer (score 0):

OK, you clearly need to first get your JavaScript fundamentals straight :) But, here are your mistakes:

On the first block of code, you seem to write an **I**mmediately **I**nvoked **F**unction **E**xpression (IIFE). In JavaScript, the following is a function declaration:

```
function myFunction() {
    // My awesome stuff
}
```

Without anyone else invoking this function, it is pretty much useless. You can invoke the function as `myFunction()` or invoke the function immediately as it is declared as:

```
(function myFunction() {
    // My awesome stuff
})();
```

This pattern is mostly used to prevent your function body from exposing variable on global scope.

so, in your case, the click event handler was never registered because the function was never invoked.

Now, you know what a function invocation is. `myFunction()` invokes the function. While `myFunction` gets a reference to a function.

When registering event handlers, the argument you pass is a reference to a function.

```
$('#myButton').click(myFunction);
```

So, you say, invoke my function `myFunction` everytime `$('#myButton')` is clicked. So, your mistake was you invoked the function `cookiesDismiss()` immediately, so what was registered as a handler for the button click was whatever was returned by your function `cookiesDismiss` which is nothing (undefined) and therefore nothing happens.

Others have placed the correct code here, but you should definitely invest time learning the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

1st: You missed the $ sign
2nd:  $('#cookiesbutton').click(cookiesDismiss());  fire the event in the beginning. 
3rd: .checked is wrong. You can use .is(":checked") 
4th: Rory McCrossan provided the solution.